# opencv warpaffine crash

Tags: opencv, crash

I get a crash (not an exception) trying to step-over a call to warpAffine:

```
void rotateImage( const Mat& source, double degree, Mat& output )
{
    Point2f src_center( source.cols / 2.0F, source.rows / 2.0F );
    Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D( src_center, degree, 1.0 );
    output.create( source.size(), source.type() );
    warpAffine( source, output, rot_mat, source.size() );
}
```

This runs well first time with a gray scale image. Yet with color image (IMREAD_COLOR - 2010 x 222 x 24bit mat) it **crashes**. No use to do try/catch ..

Any clue?

I am using windows7 + Qt5.0.1 + opencv243 compiler is visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Mystery resolved...

**OpenCV 241 works where 243 don't** ... So, If you're heading **Qt + VS2010 + Win7 use opencv 241 and avoid 243** ... I used pre-compiled opencv as provided on their site.

Ain't gonna report a bug.. I don't have the time for that, a pitty guys at opencv don't provide proper builds!

Answer (score 0):

use dst.size() instead of src.size() in warpAffine()